Symlink Messages Library Data
My hard drive is completely full on my mac, mostly due to my extensive Messages archive. I have an external drive and would like to move the data over to it using a symlink (or other solution). When I try to create a symlink I get an "operation not permitted" error, I'm assuming due to system integrity protection. What is the right way to go about doing this?
My attempts to make a symlink:
user@mac ~ % ln -s /Volumes/extssd/Library/Messages ~/Library/Messages
ln: /Users/me/Library/Messages: Operation not permitted
user@mac ~ % sudo ln -s /Volumes/extssd/Library/Messages ~/Library/Messages
Password:
ln: /Users/me/Library/Messages/Messages: Operation not permitted
user@mac ~ % sudo ln -s /Volumes/extssd/Library/Messages/Attachments ~/Library/Messages/Attachments
ln: /Users/me/Library/Messages/Attachments: Operation not permitted


What exact symlink did you try?

@mmmmmm edited my question to include my symlink attempts.
